# Can TinyMCE be used to edit full web pages?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm working on creating a visual editor and am wondering if TinyMCE could be used to edit an entire webpage.

It loads content in through an iFrame (I assume using document.designMode, but could be wrong on that) so I'm thinking it could be.

Does anyone know if there are any libraries or examples of this being done out there? I haven't been able to find any information on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the examples on the tinymce website:  http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full_page.php

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for! I'll mark this as the answer as soon as the site lets me.